# How To Detect a Button Click in the Expanded Accordion Row

Tags: php, jquery, accordion

I have an accordion which gets populated based on a dropdown selection. In the 'details' section of each accordion row, I have a button which simply hides the entire accordion and shows a div (which is hidden by default). The div contains the same details as the row selected as well as some additional fields to allow a request be submitted for that item. The first accordion row works fine but when I click on any other row, nothing happens.

I'm assuming this is because the buttons are named the same in each row. I can easily add the row identifier to the end of the button name to differentiate each but I can't figure out how to detect which is selected in my jQuery.

The page works as follows: When a dropdown selection is made, I pass it's value to a SQL statement. Then I loop through each database row and populate my accordion control. Each row can be expanded to show a details section which contains a button used to show the hidden div. When the button is clicked, I use jQuery to pass those values to labels in the hidden div.

```
<div class="accordion" id="accordion2">
<?php
if (isset($_GET['src'])) {
// SQL stuff here

$group = null;

while ($row = odbc_fetch_array($db)) {

    if ($row['Name'] != $group) {
        echo "<div class='accordion-heading'>";
            echo "<a class='accordion-toggle' data-toggle='collapse' 
              data-parent='#accordion2' href='#", $row['Number'],"'>
              <button id='buttonAccordionToggle' 
              data-target='#", $row['Number'],"'>", $row['Name'],"</button></a>";
        echo "</div>";
        echo "<div id='", $row['Number'],"' class='accordion-body collapse'>";
            echo "<div class='accordion-inner'>";
                echo "<div class='control-group' style='min-height: 50px'>";
                    echo "<div class='row-fluid show-grid'>";
                        echo "<div class='span12'>";
                            echo "<div class='span1'>";
                                echo "<label>Name:</label>";
                            echo "</div>";
                            echo "<div class='span11'>";
                                echo "<label id='labelAccordionName'>", 
                                  $row['UserName'],"</label>";
                            echo "</div>";
                            echo "</div>";
                            echo "<div class='span12'>";
                                echo "<a id='select' class='btn'>Select</a>";
                            echo "</div>";
                        echo "</div>";
                    echo "</div>";
                echo "</div>";
            echo "</div>";

            $group = $row['Name'];
        }
    }
}
?>
</div>

<div id="divDetails" style="display: none;">
    <label>Name:</label>
    <label id="labelName"></label>
    <a id="close" class="btn">Close</a>
</div>

<script>
// Hide the accordion and show the hidden div
$('#select').click(function() {
    $('#accordion2').hide();
    $('#divDetails').show();
    // Pass the label value from the accordion row to the hidden div label
    $('#labelName').html($('#labelAccordionName').html());
});

// Hide the div and show the accordion again
$('#close').click(function() {
    $('#accordion2').show();
    $('#divDetails').hide();
});

// Only allows one row to be shown at a time
$('.accordion-toggle').click(function() {
    var $acc = $('#accordion2');
    $acc.on('show', '.collapse', function() {
        $acc.find('.collapse.in').collapse('hide');
    });
});

$(document).ready(function(){
    // On dropdown change, pass in value to populate accordion/details
    $('#dd').change(function() {
        var r = $(this).val();
        location.href = "test.php?src=" + r;
    });
});
</script>
```

I know I can add an identifier to the Select button like below but I don't know how to catch that using jQuery:

```
echo "<a id='select", $row['Number'],"' class='btn'>Select</a>";
```

Again, the first row works exactly how it should but nothing happens when I click the Select button on any of the other rows.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't duplicate element `id`'s. You already have a class of `btn` on the element, so just bind the event handler to that instead:

```
$('a.btn').click(function() {
    ...
});
```

---

#### edit

In order to get the relevant `label` text, you'll have to traverse the DOM using `this` (which refers to the clicked `btn`).

First, make sure you're not duplicating the `id` of the `label` element, change:

```
<label id='labelAccordionName'>
```

to

```
<label class='labelAccordionName'>
```

Then, you should be able to use the following (in your `a.btn` click handler):

```
$(this).parent().prev().find('.labelAccordionName').html();
```

Comment: thank you very much, the button in each row works now but no matter which row I have expanded, the label value that gets carried over is from the first row. Since the expanded row has the class 'in' applied to it, would there be a way to use that to identify the correct text to pass to the div?

Comment: you're awesome! Exactly what I was trying to do. Thank you!

Comment: After adding some more controls to my page, I've run into another speedbump. Using your solution works great as long as the Select button is in the same parent div. After the div which starts with <div class='row-fluid..., if I start another div row after it with a different label and then add the Submit button to a completely different div row, using the parent().prev().find... does not get those values. After searching the jQuery website, trying a few different approaches, I'm just not able to figure it out. If I should create a new question for this or edit the OP, please let me know.

Comment: @Brian I'd create it as another question :)

Comment: Thanks @billyonecan , just wanted to make sure I use the site correctly. Here is a link to the other question, just in case. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16589649/how-to-detect-a-button-click-in-an-expanded-accordion-row-with-multiple-labels