# How to Detect a Button Click in an Expanded Accordion Row with Multiple Labels

Tags: php, jquery, accordion

This is an extension to another post by myself ([How To Detect a Button Click in the Expanded Accordion Row](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16567978/how-to-detect-a-button-click-in-the-expanded-accordion-row)).

After adding some additional rows in the details section of my accordion control and moving the 'Select' button into a separate div, I am only getting the values from the first accordion row. This was my original issue. Just to confirm the original solution worked, if I move my 'Select' button into the save div containing the label for Location, it passes the correct location label ('labelAccordionLocation') value for what ever row I have expanded but always passes the first row's name label value. It also works correct if the 'Select' button is in the save div as the Name label ('labelAccordionName').

Based on the suggestion in my other post (which worked flawlessly for my original example), it seems that I now need to figure out how to identify the div that contains each label so I can then pass it's value when the 'Submit' button is clicked. Although, this is still just an amateur's way of thinking.

```
<div class="accordion" id="accordion2">
<?php
// SQL stuff here...
$group = null;

while ($row = odbc_fetch_array($db)) {

if ($row['Name'] != $group) {
    echo "<div class='accordion-heading'>";
        echo "<a class='accordion-toggle' data-toggle='collapse' 
          data-parent='#accordion2' href='#", $row['Number'],"'>
          <button id='buttonAccordionToggle' 
          data-target='#", $row['Number'],"'>", $row['Name'],"</button></a>";
    echo "</div>";
    echo "<div id='", $row['Number'],"' class='accordion-body collapse'>";
        echo "<div class='accordion-inner'>";
            echo "<div class='control-group' style='min-height: 50px'>";
                echo "<div class='row-fluid show-grid'>";
                    echo "<div class='span12'>";
                        echo "<div class='span1'>";
                            echo "<label>Name:</label>";
                        echo "</div>";
                        echo "<div class='span11'>";
                            echo "<label id='labelAccordionName'>", 
                              $row['Name'],"</label>";
                        echo "</div>";
                    echo "</div>";
                echo "</div>";
                echo "<div class='row-fluid show-grid'>";
                    echo "<div class='span12'>";
                        echo "<div class='span1'>";
                            echo "<label>Location:</label>";
                        echo "</div>";
                        echo "<div class='span11'>";
                            echo "<label id='labelAccordionLocation'>", 
                                     $row['Location'],"</label>";
                        echo "</div>";
                    echo "</div>";
                echo "</div>";
                echo "<div class='row-fluid show-grid'>";
                    echo "<div class='span12'>";
                            echo "<a id='select' class='btn'>Select</a>";
                        echo "</div>";
                    echo "</div>";
                echo "</div>";
            echo "</div>";
        echo "</div>";

        $group = $row['Name'];
        }
    }
}
?>
</div>

<div id="divDetails" style="display: none;">
    <label>Name:</label>
    <label id="labelName"></label><br />
    <label>Location:</label>
    <label id="labelLocation"></label><br />
    <a id="close" class="btn">Close</a>
</div>

<script>
// Hide the accordion and show the hidden div
$('a.btn').click(function() {
    $('#accordion2').hide();
    $('#divDetails').show();

    // Pass the label value from the accordion row to the hidden div label
    $('#labelName').html($('.accordion-body.in .labelAccordionName').html());
    $('#labelLocation').html($('.accordion-body.in .labelAccordionLocation').html());
});

// Hide the div and show the accordion again
$('#close').click(function() {
    $('#accordion2').show();
    $('#divDetails').hide();
});

// Only allows one row to be shown at a time
$('.accordion-toggle').click(function() {
    var $acc = $('#accordion2');
    $acc.on('show', '.collapse', function() {
        $acc.find('.collapse.in').collapse('hide');
    });
});

$(document).ready(function(){
    // On dropdown change, pass in value to populate accordion/details
    $('#dd').change(function() {
        var r = $(this).val();
        location.href = "test.php?src=" + r;
    });
});
</script>
```

I did some searching on the jQuery site to try and figure this one out but unfortunately was unable to get it working. I'll do my best to give any additional information that is needed.

**Edits**

I changed the label's to use classes instead of id's. Although a great suggestion, I did not have to apply a new class 'activeAccordion'. Since the class 'in' is applied to the expanded row, I was able to use it for access as seen below. I also updated the jsFiddle and provided a link at the bottom.

```
$('a.btn').click(function() {
    $('#accordion2').hide();
    $('#divDetails').show();

    $('#labelName').html($('.accordion-body.in .labelAccordionName').html());
    $('#labelLocation').html($('.accordion-body.in .labelAccordionLocation').html());
});
```

**Working jsFiddle**

http://jsfiddle.net/N8JuQ/

Comment: can you provide a working fiddle exemple of the generated php page? btw, add all your click events inside the document ready event, safer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

when generating html with php, as long as you are iterating be careful with IDs. Never generate same ID in a DOM, it messes things really bad. (ie. select, labelAccordionName, buttonAccordionToggle) I suggest using classes or generating unique IDs plus a generic class

you should have something like :

```
<div class="accordion" id="accordion2">
<?php
// SQL stuff here...
$group = null;

while ($row = odbc_fetch_array($db)) {

if ($row['Name'] != $group) {
    echo "<div class='accordion-heading'>";
        echo "<a class='accordion-toggle' data-toggle='collapse' 
          data-parent='#accordion2' href='#", $row['Number'],"'>
          <button class='buttonAccordionToggle' 
          data-target='#", $row['Number'],"'>", $row['Name'],"</button></a>";
    echo "</div>";
    echo "<div id='", $row['Number'],"' class='accordion-body collapse'>";
        echo "<div class='accordion-inner'>";
            echo "<div class='control-group' style='min-height: 50px'>";
                echo "<div class='row-fluid show-grid'>";
                    echo "<div class='span12'>";
                        echo "<div class='span1'>";
                            echo "<label>Name:</label>";
                        echo "</div>";
                        echo "<div class='span11'>";
                            echo "<label class='labelAccordionName'>", 
                              $row['Name'],"</label>";
                        echo "</div>";
                    echo "</div>";
                echo "</div>";
                echo "<div class='row-fluid show-grid'>";
                    echo "<div class='span12'>";
                        echo "<div class='span1'>";
                            echo "<label>Location:</label>";
                        echo "</div>";
                        echo "<div class='span11'>";
                            echo "<label class='labelAccordionLocation'>", 
                                     $row['Location'],"</label>";
                        echo "</div>";
                    echo "</div>";
                echo "</div>";
                echo "<div class='row-fluid show-grid'>";
                    echo "<div class='span12'>";
                            echo "<a class='select btn'>Select</a>";
                        echo "</div>";
                    echo "</div>";
                echo "</div>";
            echo "</div>";
        echo "</div>";

        $group = $row['Name'];
        }
    }
}
?>
</div>

<div id="divDetails" style="display: none;">
    <label>Name:</label>
    <label id="labelName"></label><br />
    <label>Location:</label>
    <label id="labelLocation"></label><br />
    <a id="close" class="btn">Close</a>
</div>

<script>
```

something like that, didn't check as you don't provided a jsfiddle. As for your data to retrieve correctly, I would suggest adding a class on active accordion-body then in your finds use this class to select the correct element :

```
$('.accordion-toggle').click(function() {
    var $acc = $('#accordion2');
    $('.activeAccordion').removeClass('activeAccordion');
$(''+$(this).next('.buttonAccordionToggle').data('target')).addClass('activeAccordion');
    $acc.on('show', '.collapse', function() {
        $acc.find('.collapse.in').collapse('hide');
    });
});
```

then use this new class :

```
$('#labelName').html($('accordion-body.activeAccordion .labelAccordionName').html()));

    $('#labelLocation').html($('accordion-body.activeAccordion .labelAccordionLocation').html()));
```

Comment: Thank you for this suggestion, I have it working now. I noticed that the class 'activeAccordion' was not being applied for some reason unknown to me but since the expanded row already gets a class 'in' applied to it from the toggle, I was able to use it to access the correct row. I included an edit at the bottom of my original post with the main change as well as an updated working jsFiddle. Thanks so much for the great help, it is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

You should consider escaping out of PHP in your if statement and only jump back in to echo the variables. Also read up on alternative syntax: http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.alternative-syntax.php

```
while ($row = odbc_fetch_array($db)) {

if ($row['Name'] != $group){
?>
    <div class='accordion-heading'>
        <a class='accordion-toggle' data-toggle='collapse' data-parent='#accordion2' href='#", <?php echo $row['Number']; ?>,"'>
          <button id='buttonAccordionToggle' data-target='#", <?php echo $row['Number']; ?>,"'>", <?php echo $row['Name']; ?>,"</button></a>
    </div>
    <div id='", <?php echo $row['Number']; ?>,"' class='accordion-body collapse'>
        <div class='accordion-inner'>
...
...
...
<?php
}
?>
```

Comment: Thanks! Let me implement that real quick. Soon as I get it done, I'll let you know the result. I'll also move all my click events in the document ready event as @TecHunter suggested. Just because I'm curious though, does moving the click events in the document ready have some type of advantage or is it just more along the lines of good practice?

Comment: Good practice + it waits that your DOM is fully loaded then add the events. If you just throw code in the <script> it will be interpreted when the JS engine reads it

Comment: Very good to know and I'll read up some more on that very soon. I threw together a quick jsFiddle (http://jsfiddle.net/N8JuQ/) as @TecHunter suggested. I just used it for the first time a couple days ago so still learning all it has to offer, very good tool though. The first time you click "Select" in one of the accordion rows, nothing gets passed but if you then click "Close" and "Submit" a second time, you can see what I'm talking about (where Submit on Row 2 passes Row 1 values).

Comment: Thanks @MichaelDuncan I edited my OP and included a working jsFiddle. I definitely will be reading the link you provided as I'm sure it will be a great deal of good knowledge.